# Obtener el numero de mes a partir del numero de semana Javascript

Tags: javascript

Buen dia

Soy nuevo en javascript me encuentro en la disyuntiva, con un combobox me retorna el año concatenado con el numero de semana
es un combobox de semanas, me encuentro en el problema de obtener el numero del mes a partir del numero de la semana obtenido del value

```
            <div class="cmb_body_container" style="">
            <div value="201822" class="cmb_item">Semana 22-18</div>
            <div value="201821" class="cmb_item">Semana 21-18</div><div value="201820" class="cmb_item">Semana 20-18</div>
            <div value="201819" class="cmb_item">Semana 19-18</div><div value="201818" class="cmb_item">Semana 18-18</div>
            <div value="201817" class="cmb_item">Semana 17-18</div><div value="201816" class="cmb_item">Semana 16-18</div>
            <div value="201815" class="cmb_item">Semana 15-18</div><div value="201814" class="cmb_item">Semana 14-18</div>
            <div value="201813" class="cmb_item">Semana 13-18</div><div value="201812" class="cmb_item">Semana 12-18</div>
            <div value="201811" class="cmb_item">Semana 11-18</div></div>
```

Cualquier ayuda es apreciada

Comment: ¿Sabes que hay semanas que están a caballo entre dos meses, verdad? En todo caso no muestras qué has intentado. Por favor revisa [help], [faq] y [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Me salio con esto

```
     function getMonthNumber(w, y) {
        var d = (1 + (w - 1) * 7); // calcula el numero de dias a partir del 1 de enero
         var fecha = new Date(y, 0, d);
         return fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    };
```